# Why data is not updating in NextJS?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I wondering why data is not updating while I make DELETE request? Should I change `getServerSideProps` to `getStaticProps` or there is other way how to solve this problem? In addition I don't want to reload page :)

```js
const Component = ({ data }) => {

  return (
    <div>
      {data.map((el) => {
        return (
          <React.Fragment key={el._id}>
            <span>{el.visitorDate}</span>
            <span>{el.visitorName}</span>
            <span>{el.visitorFamilyName}</span>
            <div>
              <button
                onClick={async () => {
                  const res = await fetch(
                    `http://localhost:4000/api/visitorData/${el._id}`,
                    {
                      method: "DELETE",
                      headers: {
                        "Content-Type": "application/json",
                      },
                    }
                  );
                }}
              >
                DELETE
              </button>
            </div>
          </React.Fragment>
        );
      })}
    </div>
  );
};

export default Component;

export async function getServerSideProps(context) {
  const res = await fetch("http://localhost:4000/api/visitorData/");
  const data = await res.json();
  return {
    props: { data },
  };
}
```

If something is unclear, let me know :)

Comment: You have to refetch the data after the DELETE request to see your changes reflected.

Answer (score 0):

You have to update the data after the DELETE request to see your changes.

Either handle this manually in `onClick`, or add `router.refresh()` after the `fetch`.